# Remove album from playlist in Audacious in Winamp mode

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu, audacious

I have installed Audacious on Xubuntu 13.04 and when it's in WinAmp mode the playlist is too small to display songs (I need to resize it but then it's bigger then a player and it don't look good) because it display Album name.

Is it posible to format what is displayd in playlists or maybe just remove the album?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change format title in Settings -> playlists